# Unable to update global variable in javascript/html function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a defined global variable that I have tried to update a number of ways, but it does not work

```
<script>
var test = 4;

 function dostuff() {


...

test=7;
or
window.test=7;
or
declare it here without the var = 7

...

}
</script>
```

then later...

```
<td><script type="text/javascript">document.write(test);</script></td>
```

output: 4!

Any help?  Help me make it say 7!

Thanks

---

dostuff() is called like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    dostuff();
});
```

if I call it normally it does update the global variable correctly, but then other stuff in this program breaks.  Any hint to update the global variable from within this $(document).ready(function()?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call the `dostuff` function?

Comment: @JamesAllardice same second answer+comment :D

Comment: document.write(test) in that will be called when the document is loading. You'd be better to create a function to update the content of that table cell which can be called *after* updating the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where you are calling `dostuff()` function, but there is one thing which need to be consider, if you want variable `test` to be global for the page. Then you should declare it like this.

```
//this one is preferd
test = 4;
```

or

```
window.test = 4;
```

This should work, make sure you are calling `dostuff()`.

**Edit: Solving Function Call Problem**

So here is complete solution with overview of your problem.

**Problem:** You are calling `doStuff()` in `document.ready()` **(This got called after loading the DOM)** event and **you are printing the value of variable when DOM is loading**.

It shows **Old Value** because `doStuff()` is never got called before you printing the value in DOM.

**Solution:** There are two ways to achieve the desired output.

1. Call `doStuff()` before  starts loading **(Right after its declaration)**.
2. Create a function, which do the calculation and return the value to be Print accordingly.

**Solution 1:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
      <script>
//Should be before Body tag
       test = 4;
//Declaring function
    function doStuff()
    {
      
      test = 8;
      
    }
    //Calling right after declarion 
    doStuff();
      </script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
/*Here value is updated and ready to print any any where in the DOM*/
      <h1><script type="text/javascript">
      
        document.write(test);</script></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Live URL to [Solution 1](http://jsbin.com/esonub/6/edit)

**Solution 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /*Should be before Body tag*/
   test = 4;
    
function doStuff()
{
  /*Changing value and returing it.*/
  test = 8;
  return test;
  
}

  </script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><script type="text/javascript">
    /*Calling function and printing returned value*/
    document.write(doStuff());</script></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Live URL to [Solution 2](http://jsbin.com/utopiz/1/edit)

Hope this will help, let me know if any thing else is there, if nothing Accpet as answer!!

Comment: dostuff() is called like this.

$(document).ready(function(){
    dostuff();
});

if I call it normally it does update the global variable correctly, but then other stuff in this program breaks. Any hint to update the global variable from within this $(document).ready(function()?

Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewClarkson Just made an edit according to your problem!!

Comment: Hey, is there away to refresh the html portion of the DOM without relaoding the whole plage?

Thanks!

Comment: There you have to use AJAX according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you're not calling your `dostuff()` function anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Head tag scripts don't actually execute functions, they just define them. You have to execute the function with a function call from somewhere in the document.  This function call can be attached to the page's onload event to make it execute automatically when the page is loaded, or it can be attached to some other event, like onclick, so you can trigger it later.

Declaring a global variable in the way that you did lacks descriptive power; when a global variable is declared, it is attached to the window object. Thus, when you declare one, declare it like so:

```
var window.varName = value;
```

While it does the exact same thing, it does help you to explicitly express what is actually going on, which is almost always better than the alternative.